# Do the ListView Control have IsSelected Property in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp-xaml, listviewitem

if it do ,how should I binding Visibility to ListViewItem's IsSelected Property?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to refer to the documentation than wait for an answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The ListViewItem class provides the container for items displayed in a ListView control. You populate the ListView by adding objects directly to its Items collection or by binding its ItemsSource property to a data source. When items are added to the ListView, a ListViewItem container is created automatically for each item in the collection.

For more info, please refer the [Remark of the ListViewItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewitem#remarks).

We should be able to use the the `SelectionChangedEventArgs.AddedItems` to get a list that contains the items that were selected. We also can use the `SelectionChangedEventArgs.RemovedItems` to get a list that contains the items that were unselected.

We can define the `IsSelected` property in the Class, the Class should inherit the `INotifyPropertyChanged`. In the `SelectionChanged` event, we can set the Selected Item and UnSelect Item to the IsSelected property of the Item.

For example:

```
public class Item : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _title;
    private bool _isSelected;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set
        {
            _title = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get { return _isSelected; }
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsSelected");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can bind the `Visibility` to the `IsSelected` without converting the type.

For example:

```
<ListView Name="MyListView" SelectionChanged="MyListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Title}"  Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

The code behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> Items;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    Items.Add(new Item());
    Items[0].Title = "Title1";
    Items.Add(new Item());
    Items[1].Title = "Title2";
    MyListView.ItemsSource = Items;
}

private void MyListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Item item in e.RemovedItems)
    {
        item.IsSelected = false;
    }

    foreach (Item item in e.AddedItems)
    {
        item.IsSelected = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean I need  to add a isSelected property in class which binded as ItemSource?